# Limit of contour integral as radius of integration approaches 0.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-integration

[image: Qn]

Apologies for the link, but can someone help me with this complex analysis qn?

Comment: My hint would be to use the Residue theorem. Our function has a pole at $z = z_0,$ and because our $r$ is going to $0$ this should be the only pole in the limiting case, since every other pole would have to be some nonzero radius away. Can you find what the order of the pole is? What is the residue at the pole?

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thanks for the reply! I have tried using that by expanding the laurent series to find the coefficient of 1 / (z-z0), but I'm not sure of the r->0 part. Do you have a more riggorous way of proving?

Comment: I would advise against using the Laurent expansion here, there may be something I'm missing but intuitively it seems like it would get ugly fast, I conceptualized that part using the definition of the order of a pole or zero, after which I think the order of the pole follows pretty directly. Also sorry, but can you clarify your question about the $r \to 0$ bit a little?

Comment: @StephenDonovan Oh I meant as in the qn wants us to have r->0. I tried using ML-inequality to derive something I can do with squeeze theorem, but didn't work.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I think it's a bit indirect for this problem. I would suggest you think of this less as a limit problem and more as an integration problem, and see if you can just compute the answer directly.